# reshaping image array [n, width, height] to [n, height, width, channel]

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have images that consisted of single digits and have width=32,height=60. I am trying to concatenate them to get at most 5 digits images.

I am producing single digits images like following;

```
def gen(n=10, max_digs=1, width=32):
    capgen = ImageCaptcha(width=width, height=60)
    data = []
    target = []
    for i in range(n):
        x = np.random.randint(0, 10 ** max_digs)
        img = misc.imread(capgen.generate(str(x)))
        img = np.mean(img, axis=2)[:, :width]
        data.append(img.flatten())
        target.append(x)
    return np.array(data), np.array(target)
```

Then I am trying to concatenate them with the following method

```
def generate_dataset(X, y):
    X_len = X.shape[0]
    X_gen = np.zeros((X_len, height, width * n_len, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    y_gen = [np.zeros((X_len, n_class), dtype=np.uint8) for i in range(n_len)]
    # generate random numbers of digits
    n_digit = random.randint(1, 6)
    for j in range(X_len):
        n_digit = random.randint(1, 5)
        for i in range(n_digit):
            index = random.randint(0, X_len - 1)
            image = X[index]
            label = y[index]
            X_gen[j][:, i*height:width + i * width, 0] = image
            y_gen[i][j][label] = 1
        for i in range(n_digit, n_len):
            y_gen[i][j][10] = 1
    return X_gen, y_gen
```

However, It gives me the error "could not broadcast input array from shape (32,60) into shape (60,0)"

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some example inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: @Allen The X input has shape (n, 32, 60) and I want take the output as    (n, 60, 32*n_len, 1) which corresponds to (n, 60, 160, 1)

Comment: @Allen Also, if I generated the pictures as 60*60 at the beginning. It is working

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: @Allen     X_gen[j][:, i*height:width + i * width, 0] = image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems the shapes of the left and right don't match.

```
X_gen[j][:, i*height:width + i * width, 0]
```

has a shape of (60, 32) and the image is of shape (32,60)

Maybe try the following to see if it works?

```
X_gen[j][:, i*height:width + i * width, 0] = image.T
```

**Update**

Finally this change fixed the problem:

```
X_gen[j][:, i*width: (i+1)*width, 0] = image.T
```

Comment: I tried but not its saying; "could not broadcast input array from shape (60,32) into shape (60,4)"

Comment: What's the output of X_gen.shape, height and weight?

Comment: (10, 60, 160, 1) which corresponds to (n, height, width, channel)

Comment: can you do a print(X_gen.shape),print(j), print(i), print(height), print(width) before the error line?

Comment: respectively (10, 60, 160, 1)
0
0
60
32

Comment: This is weird. Those numbers look correct. Can you also do a print(X_gen[j][:, i*height:width + i * width, 0].shape) before the error line?

Comment: it is printing (60, 32)

Comment: The two error messages you've put here "could not broadcast input array from shape (32,60) into shape (60,0)" and "could not broadcast input array from shape (60,32) into shape (60,4)" seems to suggest there's something strange going on in your code. It indicates the shape of X_gen[j][:, i*height:width + i * width, 0] may change during execution time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144662/discussion-between-cano-and-allen).